# Filed Value Factor not working in elastic search

Tags: search, elasticsearch

GET test/_search?size=3

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "function_score":{  
         "query":{  
            "match_all":{  

            }
         },
         "functions":[  
            {  
               "field_value_factor":{  
                  "field":"maxDocs",
                  "factor":1.2,
                  "modifier":"sqrt"
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode":"multiply"
      }
   }
}
```

maxDocs has values 10,20,30,40,50,60 etc ... But when i run this query i am not getting the top 3 macDocs values. 40, 50, 60 is what i am expecting in the results.

Comment: @ Mysterion Can you help us on this ?

Comment: How do the documents look like? What you get in the result? Provide more details